# json unmarshal in gloang for complex json data

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

i want to json unmarshal following data in golang :

```
{
RESPONSE : {
    CODE : "123"
    NEW_RESPONSE :{
            0:[
                {
                    key1:val1,
                    key2:val2

                },
                {
                    key3:val3,
                    key4:val4
                }
            ]
            1:[
                {
                    key5:val5,
                    key6:val6,
                    key7:val7

                },
                {
                    key31:val31,
                    key42:val42
                }
            ]
            2:{
                key8:val8,
                key9:val9,
                key1-:val10
            }
            3:{}
    }
}
```

}

I want to access every key of this data. What i was trying is

```
type testData struct{
Code string  `json:"CODE"`
NewResponse  map[string]interface{} `json:"NEW_RESPONSE"`}

type GetData struct{
TestResponse testData `json:"RESPONSE"`}
```

After this I am not able to furthur use "NewResponse". Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access elements of `NewResponse` using the key:

```
elem:=NewResponse["0"]
```

Looking at the input document, `elem` is an array of objects. The rest of the code will use type assertions:

```
if arr, ok:=elem.([]interface{}); ok {
   // arr is a JSON array
   objElem:=arr[0].(map[string]interface{})
   for key,value:=range objElem {
      // key: "key1"
      // value: "val1"
      val:=value.(string)
      ...
   }
} else if obj, ok:=elem.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
   // obj is a JSON object
   for key, val:=range obj {
      // key: "key1"
      value:=val.(string)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The number of keys in NewResponse is dynamic and can not be preknown.   Also,  **Looking at the input document, elem is an array of objects.**  elem is array of objects or object directly.

Comment: You can loop through the keys of NewResponse: `for key,value:=range NewResponse`. The above code already deals with elements being arrays of objects or single objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  **elem.(map[string]interface{}) ** this is not identifying the struct /  object.

Comment: You have to go through the keys. See the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

Plz validate your json format

this may solve your purpose.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

    func main() {
    Json := `{
"RESPONSE" : {
    "CODE" : "123",
    "NEW_RESPONSE" :{
            "0":{
            "s" : 1,
            "s1" :2,
            "s3": 3 
            }                      
    }
}
}`

// Declared an empty interface
var result map[string]interface{}

// Unmarshal or Decode the JSON to the interface.
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(Json), &result)    
if err != nil{      
fmt.Println("Err : ",err)
}else{
fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: The json format I shared is correct and is in check with my requirement. I have also used the method of decode you are suggesting in the past but its irrelevant in current scenario. Thanks for answering though.